# What algorithm is this?

Tags: algorithms

I have some vague recollections from my algorithms courses, but nothing specific comes to mind.

let S be a multiset of things we are interested in.

As input, we get T, s<sub>1</sub>, s<sub>2</sub>, ... s<sub>n</sub>, all of which are subsets of S, except that T can have duplicates .

As output we get whether it is possible to pick exactly 1 element from each s<sub>i</sub> so that we end up with T. What would be really nice is if in the case of failure it told you which s<sub>i</sub>'s were not covered by T (although this isn't really well defined when there's non-empty intersections in the s<sub>i</sub>'s).

In my case, most of the time there won't be many elements which appear in more than one s<sub>i</sub>'s, but I have to account for the possibility. Also, an 'online' algorithm in which you provide the s<sub>i</sub>'s up front, and then pass in elements of T one at a time would be convenient.

This is almost like the [exact hitting set problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover#Exact_hitting_set), but I am given T, rather than trying to find a subset of T which has this property.

Comment: Since *S* is a multi-set, might *T* contain duplicates as well?  So how are you combining the picked elements?  Will you discard multiple items?  I'm asking because if you don't discard duplicates, since you say that you get *all* multi-subsets of *S*, this will narrow the possible choices for *T* dramatically.

Comment: Well, in my case, S is the 'universe' of items, I guess it's not really a multiset. All the subsets may contain duplicates though.

Comment: I'm confused by the “*all* sub-multisets” in your question.  Do you mean that once *S* is fixed, all the *s1*, …, *sn* are determined except for reordering?  And expanding on this, if *s1* = {1, 2} and *s2* = {1}.  If I pick 1 from *s1* and 1 from *s2*, will the union (as defined in your domain) be {1, 1} or {1}?

Comment: Sorry for the confusing wording, I've edited the question in an attempt at clarification

Comment: The si's are arbitrary nonempty subsets of S, and there is an arbitrary number of them.

Comment: And if you pick the same element from two of the sets, then T must have (at least) two copies of that element.

Comment: Well, there always has to be N si's, where N is the cardinality of T.

Comment: Thanks, I think that I understand your problem now, except that you could add whether the *si* may contain duplicates. (You simply call them “sets” in your question while everything else is called a “multi-set”, but I don't think this is very important to the theoretical problem.)  Something is telling me that this should be possible in polynomial time and something else is telling me that linear programming might work.  Unfortunately, I don't have enough time to think about this in detail, right now.  Maybe I'll come back later.

Comment: Yeah, the si's shouldn't contain duplicates, although it doesn't really matter, since you have to pick exactly one element from each. A particular element may be part of multiple si's though.